# How can I call a method in Vue while the rendering takes place

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

**This so far works as expected**. This means, while rendering, the **Json data** is 'transformed' correctly to a **csv String** as the Attribute value.

**Json**:

```
"functions": {
    "function": [
        {
            "name": "foo"
        },
        {
            "name": "bar"
        }
    ]
},
```

**Html**:

```
<input allowedfunctions="foo,bar" />
```

**Vue - templating**:

```
<input
    :allowedfunctions="data.functions ?
                    data.functions.function.map(function(e) { return e.name }, data.functions.function).join(',') :
                    ''"
/>
```

Now, I want to refactor and make this more readable.
So, **how can I call a method while the rendering takes place**?

**Something like this would be awesome**:

```
<input :allowedfunctions="getAllowedFunctions(data.functions);" />
```

Comment: You've put the `:` in the wrong place in your last example. Put it directly before the prop name and the code you suggested should call the method `getAllowedFunctions` no problem.

Comment: Thx, done and updated.

Comment: You also need to remove the `;` from the end. Are you saying that the code doesn't work? Are you seeing an error message? Have you tried putting console logging inside your method to check whether it is being called?

Comment: Once again, thx :-) And it is working now. I had the function implemented as 'computed' and the ';' caused a 'Unexpected token' error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now it is working as expected.
Due to the comments, here I had to **remove the semicolon**:

```
<input :allowedfunctions="getAllowedFunctions(data.functions)" />
```

And further, the function must be **implemented as 'method'** and not as 'computed':

```
methods: {
    getAllowedFunctions(functions: any) {
      if (functions) {
        return functions.function.map(function(e: any) { return e.name }, functions.function).join(',');
      }
    }
}
```